# What is causing this "invalid top-level expression" error in my GULP gulpfile.js file?

Tags: javascript, windows, gulp

I get an error after I start gulp. I have taken out all other plugins to find problem:

```
[gulp-sass] source string:1: error: invalid top-level expression
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('app/assets/sass/styles.sass')
        .pipe(sass({
            errLogToConsole: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/css'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function() {
    gulp.watch("app/assets/sass/*.sass", ['sass']);
});
```

Windows 7

Comment: The problem might be in your SASS...

Comment: problem is not in the sass file. I checked with the sass file only having two lines just to make sure.

Comment: I found the problem but not solution. If I change the gulp.src to anything other than what it's currently set (the existing correct directory) the error will go away.

Comment: SASS has two syntaxes — SASS and SCSS. I got this error after switching from SCSS to SASS. You haven't provided your SASS file so I have to guess, but from what you've said it's probably the same cause. @mastertinner's answer has the solution.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use the indented syntax (.sass) as the top level file, use

`pipe(sass({ indentedSyntax: true }))`

instead of

`pipe(sass())`.

Answer (score 4):

Can you try to use the option `sourceComments` and set it to `normal` in your `sass` ? It seems to have some problems if you don't pass it.

So try to change your task as follow :

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {

  gulp.src('app/assets/sass/styles.sass')
    .pipe(sass({
        errLogToConsole: true,
        sourceComments : 'normal'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public_html/assets/css'))
});
```

See the [related issue](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/55#issuecomment-47708591) of [**gulp-sass**](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/). Alternatively, you can still use [**gulp-ruby-sass**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass).

Answer (score 0):

Hilariously, the problem for me was that the plugin `gulp-sass` ignores the extension of the top level file and parses as SCSS no matter what.

Includes worked correctly, so the solution was to make a one liner inclusion at the top.