# Grunt Sass Task Error when Running "Grunt Compile"?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

When running "Grunt Compile" I get the below error related to Sass Task? I have checked that all files exist and that there are no syntax errors. See Gist link below for "gruntfile.js". This is for a pre-existing grunt project on Windows 7 and all that was required was that I installed sass, npm, grunt & setup environment variables. And it's not working.

```
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
Warning: source string:1: error: invalid top-level expression
Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

https://gist.github.com/Cypher278999/6e2703dc3391e4509098

Comment: Does the Sass files compile when you use the Sass command directly (ie. not using Grunt)?

Comment: @cimmanon 17, I was able to create a .css file using SASS but with variable and mixin errors. *Note: that this exact project is being used with no issues by other developers so it should work. There has to be something simple that I do not have configured correctly. Also, I did report the "grunt compile" error at gruntjs' repository (github) and the reply was it has something to do with the SASS task and for me to please check the sass:dev task. Thanks for any additional help and/or pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225680/what-is-causing-this-invalid-top-level-expression-error-in-my-gulp-gulpfile-js